# Access hdfs from outside the cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a hadoop cluster on aws and I am trying to access it from outside the cluster through a hadoop client. I can successfully `hdfs dfs -ls` and see all contents but when I try to `put` or `get` a file I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.displayError(FsShell.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

I have hadoop 2.6.0 installed in both my cluster and my local machine. I have copied the conf files of the cluster to the local machine and have these options in hdfs-site.xml (along with some other options).

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

My core-site.xml contains a single property in both the cluster and the client:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://public-dns:9000</value>
  <description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>
```

I found similar questions but wasn't able to find a solution to this.

Comment: There aren't enough details in this question to help you. How did you install the hadoop command line utilities on your local machine?

Comment: And your `core-site.xml`?

Comment: So... I can't find anything really online to help with this. The alternative is to SSH into the cluster to run all the `hdfs dfs` commands.

Comment: thanks for trying. I could not find anything either.

Comment: I had a thought that though you can access the namenode at port 9000 to run the `hdfs dfs -ls` command to get file metadata, you would also need to access all the datanodes in order to do `-get` or `-put`. I imagine **that** is what the error is, though it is weird to me that that would be a null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you SSH into that machine?

I know this is a **very bad** idea but to get the work done, you can first copy that file on machine using `scp` and then SSH into that cluster/master and do `hdfs dfs -put` on that copied local file.

You can also automate this via a script but again, **this is just to get the work done for now.**

Wait for someone else to answer to know the proper way!

Comment: And indeed that's what I ended up doing since I could not find a solution. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my cluster when running hadoop fs -get and I could resolve it. Just check if all your data nodes are resolvable using FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain Name) from your local host. In my case nc command was successful using ip addresses for data nodes but not with host name.
run below command :
for i in `cat /<host list file>`; do nc -vz $i 50010; done
50010 is default datanode port

when you run any hadoop command it try to connect to data nodes using FQDN and thats where it gives this weird NPE.

Do below export and run your hadoop command
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console

you will see this NPE comes when it is trying to connect to any datanode for data transfer.

I had a java code which was also doing hadoop fs -get using APIs and there ,exception was more clearer

java.lang.Exception: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Let me know if this helps you.